# Python/Modelica: simulateExtendedModel

Tags: python, modelica, dymola

I want to run modelica(Dymola) parameter studies in python.

My code:

```
output = dymola.simulateExtendedModel(models, starttime (=0), endtime(=31536000=, timeInterval(=120),...);
```

I set: 
I expected 262800 values for each variable – but I just get hourly values (8761).
When I export the values direct in Dymola – I get 262800.

Comment: We don't have nearly enough context to help you. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the new python-interface, but according to the document-command from dymola-script:

simulateExtendedModel: Real finalValues[size(finalNames, 1)] "Values at end-point";

So I expect to get only one value for each variable - the value at the end-point. Please try using the "simulateModel" command or "simulateMultiResultsModel" if the trajectories are needed.